# save custom array into Core Data

Tags: arrays, macos, cocoa, core-data, swift3

i have this code to save an simple string array into core data und convert it back to an array:

```
// Convert it to binary data
let array = ["Haus", "Tier","Tür"]
let x = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: positionen)

// Convert it to an array
let data = coreData.value(forKey: "arrayPos") as! NSData
let unarchiveObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as Data)
let arrayObject = unarchiveObject as! [String]
```

But if would like save an array like this:

```
struct ArrayData {
    var positionsname:String
    var anzahl:Double
    var einheit:String
    var einzelpreis:Double
    var typ:String
    var katalog:Bool
}
var array = [ArrayData ]()
```

My app will crashes.

```
2017-06-15 09:38:48.212788+0200 Programm[9364:608571] -[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000f4700
2017-06-15 09:38:48.214663+0200 Programm[9364:608571] [General] -[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000f4700
2017-06-15 09:38:48.285393+0200 Programm[9364:608571] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb49ac57b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffc9bf01da objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb4a2cf14 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb491fc93 ___forwarding___ + 1059
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb491f7e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fffb63ac95a _encodeObject + 1241
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fffb63adf0c -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 460
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fffb63ac95a _encodeObject + 1241
    8   Foundation                          0x00007fffb63e8492 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 156
    9   Programm                            0x000000010002177b _TFC8Programm18DokumentController12saveCoreDatafT_T_ + 907
    10  Programm                            0x0000000100020ef9 _TFC8Programm18DokumentController11getObjectIDfCSo14NSNotificationT_ + 377
    11  Programm                            0x00000001000213da _TToFC8Programm18DokumentController11getObjectIDfCSo14NSNotificationT_ + 58
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb493954c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb493944b _CFXRegistrationPost + 427
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb49391b2 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb48f7782 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 2018
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb48f676b _CFXNotificationPost + 667
    17  Foundation                          0x00007fffb6338907 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    18  Programm                            0x0000000100003eae _TFC8Programm16KundenController20showSelectedDocumentfT_T_ + 2094
    19  Programm                            0x0000000100003458 _TFC8Programm16KundenController21outlineViewClickedRowfCSo13NSOutlineViewT_ + 5672
    20  Programm                            0x000000010000366a _TToFC8Programm16KundenController21outlineViewClickedRowfCSo13NSOutlineViewT_ + 58
    21  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fffca7033a7 _os_activity_initiate_impl + 53
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fffb2b9a721 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 456
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fffb267ecc4 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fffb26f5d10 -[NSTableView _sendAction:to:row:column:] + 111
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fffb26f450f -[NSTableView mouseDown:] + 7439
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fffb26f25d0 -[NSOutlineView mouseDown:] + 74
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fffb2d1624f -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6341
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fffb2d12a6c -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 1942
    29  AppKit                              0x00007fffb2d11f0a -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 541
    30  AppKit                              0x00007fffb2b96681 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 1145
    31  AppKit                              0x00007fffb2411427 -[NSApplication run] + 1002
    32  AppKit                              0x00007fffb23dbe0e NSApplicationMain + 1237
    33  Programm                            0x000000010001319d main + 13
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffca4d1235 start + 1
    35  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
2017-06-15 09:38:48.286692+0200 Programm[9364:608571] *** -[NSKeyedArchiver dealloc]: warning: NSKeyedArchiver deallocated without having had -finishEncoding called on it.
```

can anyone explain me, what i do wrong?
i working with swift 3 for OS X

Comment: Related to Core Data `ArrayData` is supposed to be an entity and the members are the attributes. (And don't use `NS...` classes in Swift if there is a native equivalent - here `NSData`).

Comment: That's the designated way to handle *records* in Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:)`, the root object must conform to `NSCoding`. With an array, every member of the array must conform. You get this error because `ArrayData` doesn't do that. The stack trace shows that the `NSCoding` method `encodeWithCoder` was called on something that doesn't implement that method.

Note that conforming to `NSCoding` requires inheriting from `NSObject`, which means that you can't use it in a Swift struct.